# Android findViewById returning null

Tags: android, null, findviewbyid

I'm using a button to call a method that just places input text into a textview. Whenever I use findViewById, it returns null.

```
public void encode(View view){
  TextView out = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.encoderout);
  EditText in = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.encoderin);
  out.setText(in.getText().toString());
  out.setTypeface(font);
}
```

My xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/encoderin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text to encode"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/encoderbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="encode"
        android:text="Encode!"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:id="@+id/encoderout"
    android:text="test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Almost every post I could find said that cleaning the project helped solve the problem but not in this case.

**EDIT**: ADDITIONAL INFO

I'm using Fragments, and this is my fragment code

```
public static class Encoder extends Fragment{
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.encoder, container, false);       
    return view;
  }
}
```

It's calling up into the Activity because of the way buttons work. I can call the find methods fine in the fragment, but not when I have to go back to the activity.

I can verify the view is not null, it prints out fine when the toString is called in the method.

**Solution**: Never realized that I had to use the main view, thought I was SUPPOSE to use the button view. I'm very new to this (started today) thankyou everyone for the input!

Comment: Did you call `setContentView()` before calling `findViewById`?

Comment: paast all your activity code, your view is null

Comment: Are you certain `encode()` is being called with a View using the layout you've shown?

Comment: Try `findViewById(R.id.encoderout)` instead of `view.findViewById(R.id.encoderout)`

Comment: I'm using Fragments and the button in the fragment is calling up into the activity for the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/encoderbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="encode"
    android:text="Encode!"/>
```

The parameter `view` in callback method `encode(View view)` in the Java code is supplied with the `Button` view itself but not the `Activity`.

See Reference below:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment`s don't receive `onClick`s methods that are declared in the XML. You need to define `encode` in your `Activity` instead, then direct the desired behavior to the appropriate `Fragment`. Annoying, but that's the way it's done. I suggest you just implement the `OnClickListener` programatically in your `Fragment` code to avoid intertwining the behavior of your fragment and activity.

Comment: That's what I did for it. I declared encode in the activity. I may have to just do it programatically though, can't seem to find another way

Comment: It's better practice to keep all of your behavior within the `Fragment` itself. Personally, I think the framework developers messed up with the `onClick` stuff... seems really stupid to have to forward the behavior back up from the Activity. It's totally fine implementing it in your `Fragment` programmatically instead.